# How to make side-nav stick to top-left when full-height is exceeded?

Tags: html, css

I want my `side-nav` is scrollable when its `height` exceeded(`550px`).I made it always centered vertically.But when screen `height` is less than `550px`,I can scroll but not compeletely.Because it should have `margin` a little bit from `top`.

**Here you can see**
[image]

Two of those icons on the `top` aren't visible and reachable.

After `550px height`,I tried to give top margin in terms of `vh` but didnt work.

```
 @media only screen and (max-height: 550px) {
    .menu {
        margin-top:30vh;
    }
  }
```

I need to calculate this top dynamically but how?I wish I could use `calc()` function but as I know its only for `width` and `height` responsive calculations.

```css
*,*::after,*::before{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,body{
    font-size:62,5%;
    background-color: #000 ;
}
body{
    box-sizing: border-box;
} 
.vertical-center {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }

.responsive {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }

  .imgContainer{
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 4px solid yellow;
  }
  .menu{
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color:#fff;
    padding:10px; 
    height: auto;
    width: fit-content;
  }
  .myIcon{
      margin-bottom:20px;
      font-size:40px;
      color:#000;
      display: block;
  }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/icon-font.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.css">
            <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon.png">
                    </head>
        <body>   

                <div class="menu" >
                    <a href=""><i class="ion-crop myIcon"></i></a>
                    <a href=""><i class="ion-android-color-palette myIcon"></i></a>
                    <a href=""><i class="ion-android-contract myIcon"></i></a>
                    <a href=""><i class="ion-android-options myIcon"></i></a>
                    <a href=""><i class="ion-android-sync myIcon"></i></a>
                    <a href=""><i class="ion-contrast myIcon"></i></a>
                    <a href=""><i class="ion-ios-analytics myIcon"></i></a>
                    <a href=""><i class="ion-ios-color-wand myIcon"></i></a>
                </div>
                    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/257360/pexels-photo-257360.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="Nature" class="responsive">
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `!important` after the `margin-top` ? Sometimes you need to force your usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you menu css to not be positioned absolutely. This way when you scroll you will scroll the sidebar menu when the menu height exceeds the screen height.

```
.menu{
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color:#fff;
    padding:10px; 
    height: auto;
    width: fit-content;
  }
```

Comment: Awesome.I didnt think about changing position due to height changes This worked:   @media only screen and (max-height: 550px) {
    .menu {
       position:relative;
       transform:translateY(0%);
    }
  }

Answer (score 1):

Using your initial code and adding `max-height: 100vh; overflow: auto` to `.menu {}` will do the trick, answering your question. Cleaner code is better, I prefer Mahatmasamatman's answer...

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  font-size: 62, 5%;
  background-color: #000;
}

body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.vertical-center {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.responsive {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.imgContainer {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 4px solid yellow;
}

.menu {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  height: auto;
  width: fit-content;
  max-height: 100vh; /* ADDED */
  overflow: auto; /* ADDED */
}

.myIcon {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #000;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/icon-font.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon.png">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="menu">
    <a href=""><i class="ion-crop myIcon"></i></a>
    <a href=""><i class="ion-android-color-palette myIcon"></i></a>
    <a href=""><i class="ion-android-contract myIcon"></i></a>
    <a href=""><i class="ion-android-options myIcon"></i></a>
    <a href=""><i class="ion-android-sync myIcon"></i></a>
    <a href=""><i class="ion-contrast myIcon"></i></a>
    <a href=""><i class="ion-ios-analytics myIcon"></i></a>
    <a href=""><i class="ion-ios-color-wand myIcon"></i></a>
  </div>
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/257360/pexels-photo-257360.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="Nature" class="responsive">
</body>

</html>
```